# Missing Applessed movie

Tags: appleseed

I'm looking for an Appleseed movie that I can't find.

It's the one where japan is hidden from all satelites and the team must go there. Upon arriving its a wasteland. Giant Dune-esgue worms made of junk have just destroyed everything. Some kind of backstory about the japanese government attempting to bioengineer its citizens by making them cyborgs at the cellular level.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Please be aware identification requests are more likely to be closed or downvoted for several reasons explained in this meta post : https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions

Comment: @Nevios you generally are right however we allow identification within a known series like music, characters of scenes. however this is an odd case and while i am worried this might be a back door for ID requests i'd be willing to let this slide for now. if people try and abuse this by intentionally guessing an incorrect series for a scene just so they can get it corrected they'll find i have some ideas in how to stop that

Comment: @Memor-X I agree this is an odd case so i wanted to warn the OP and flag it because i was kinda confusing. However, since it has a quite good answer, i guess it's ok.What about your ideas ?
Because i've been recently focusing on closing many ID requests

Comment: OP doesn't seem to have been asking this question in bad faith, but OP also got their answer, so I'm going to go ahead and close this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for **Vexille : 2007 Nihon Sakoku**, rather than Appleseed. The plot all seems to match : [Vexille - MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/2746/Vexille__2077_Nihon_Sakoku)

[image: Vexile]

Comment: You are correct sir. Thank you. I would have sworn on my life it was appleseed, probably because I rented them from the library at the same time.